# Google map is showing different location while searching a address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I build the application for car pooling, in which i have used Google map to search the ride. Every thing is working fine expect one strange thing is happening when i am searching for a address in Google map, official site  is showing marker at some different location For Example:-

suppose i am searching for:" Manhattan Associates India Dev Center, EPIP Zone, Bangalore, Karnataka, India"

official site is showing marker at the correct location but in my site it is showing marker at some different place,I inspect the response of the route request using console.log in which start address is coming as "EPIP Zone, Bangalore, Karnataka, India" . I don't know why complete address is not coming.Please help me for this strange thing.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724672/google-map-and-api-shows-different-results/14730073#14730073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=+Manhattan+Associates+India+Dev+Center,+EPIP+Zone,+Bangalore,+Karnataka,+India&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&hq=Manhattan+Associates+India+Dev+Center,&hnear=EPIP+Zone,+Bangalore,+Bengaluru+Urban,+Karnataka,+India&t=m&z=14) shows 2 results for that query (and provides 8 additional matches...)

That location is in the [Places database](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxC.html?q=Manhattan%20Associates%20India%20Dev%20Center,%20EPIP%20Zone,%20Bangalore,%20Karnataka,%20India).

But as there is no "address" the geocoder can't find it.  You can use the geographic coordinates from the Places result.

Comment: Thanks for the response.... i agree with your point that Google maps is showing two result but what about the below address

"iGATE Global Solutions Limited, EPIP Zone, Bangalore, Karnataka, India "

for this location response is showing 

EPIP Zone, Bangalore, Karnataka, India (12.97654,77.72521000000006)

but if you will search same address in google map it will show you some different location

Comment: That [result shown on Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=iGATE+Global+Solutions+Limited,+EPIP+Zone,+Bangalore,+Karnataka,+India&sll=12.967323,77.734432&sspn=0.064739,0.111494&vpsrc=0&ie=UTF8&hq=iGATE+Global+Solutions+Limited,&hnear=EPIP+Zone,+Bangalore,+Bengaluru+Urban,+Karnataka,+India&t=m&z=16) is also a result from [Places](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxC.html?q=iGATE%20Global%20Solutions%20Limited,%20EPIP%20Zone,%20Bangalore,%20Karnataka,%20India), not from the Geocoder.

Comment: can u please give me some example to understand this thing because as per my understanding you are asking me to use Geocoder first to get the latlong and then pass those latlong to the request of DirectionsService. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No.  The geocoder doesn't work for those locations, you need to use the Places API to get the geographic coordinates, then pass the geographic coordinates (as google.maps.LatLng objects) into the DirectionsService.

Comment: your quick response is really Appreciated. Now i have one more doubt i got your point why i not getting proper location but while drawing the route over Google map offical site from "BTM 2nd Stage, BTM Layout 2nd Stage, Bangalore, Karnataka, India" to "Manhattan Associates India Dev Center, EPIP Zone, Bangalore, Karnataka, India" it is showing me exact location of both source and destination. But when i am searching the same in my application, autocomplete is  suggesting both location but while plotting over the map it is plotting different route(click of marker it is showing correct address)